# Mean of rows from two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I have two dataframes who's columns share the same names. I want to find the row means from the two columns of the different dataframes and save that in a newdataframe. The new dataframe would have the same number of rows (0-95) and the values would be the average of the same row using the two dataframes as inputs. The dataframes have different index values the first one goes from 0-95, and the second 96-191, but they have the same length( which is 96).

[image: dataframe2]

[image: dataframe3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
df_new2['v2']=df_new3.average.values
df_new2.mean(axis=1)
```